# How to expose MinIO outside cluster ip

Tags: kubernetes, minio, k3s

I have setup MinIO with Kubernetes (K3s) in one node.

Command `kubectl logs mypod-0 -n minio` returns the following:

- API: http://10.42.0.14:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
- Console: http://10.42.0.14:41989 http://127.0.0.1:41989

I have access to the console from the second link and by using python I can list the buckets inside minio with:

```
import logging
from minio import Minio
from minio.error import S3Error

# execute from IDE terminal
minio = Minio(
    '10.42.0.14:9000',
    access_key='chesAccesskeyMinio',
    secret_key='chesSecretkey',
    secure=False,
)


def list_all_buckets():
    bucket_list = minio.list_buckets()
    for bucket in bucket_list:
        objects = minio.list_objects(bucket.name, recursive=True)
        print (bucket.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        list_all_buckets()
    except S3Error as exc:
        print("error occurred.", exc)
        logging.critical("Object storage not reachable")
```

My question is how to expose this IP to be accesible from outside my network (both he console and the API).
Do I have to use ingress?

**UPDATED based on answer and comments**

I have two services

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ches
  namespace: minio
  labels:
    app: ches
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: ches
  ports:
  - port: 9011
    name: ches
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ches-service
  namespace: minio
  labels:
    app: ches
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: ches
  ports:
  - port: 9012
    targetPort: 9011
    protocol: TCP
```

and then I created an Ingress using

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minio
  namespace: minio
spec:
  rules:
  - host: s3.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: ches-service
            port:
              number: 9000
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

Command `kubectl describe Ingress minio -n minio` results in:

```
Name:             minio
Namespace:        minio
Address:          192.168.1.14
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host            Path  Backends
  ----            ----  --------
  s3.example.com  
                  /   ches-service:9000 (10.42.0.14:9011)
Annotations:      <none>
Events:           <none>
```

However I cannot access `s3.example.com`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, an Ingress would allow you to expose MinIO to clients outside your clusters SDN.

You probably have a Service object already (if not, you need one, Ingress points to Service, which resolves to Pods).

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: minio
spec:
  rules:
  - host: s3.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: minio-api
            port:
              number: 9000
        path: /
        pathType: Prefix
```

If you don't have/want to use an ingresscontroller, you could use a NodePort service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio-nodeport
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    name: my-minio-pod
  type: NodePort
```

NodePorts services are allocated a unique port (within a range/could vary depending on your cluster configuration). When connecting to any node of your cluster, on that port, we would be redirected to any pod matching that Services selector.

```
$> kubectl get svc
my-nodeport-svc  NodePort 10.233.7.160 <none> 9000:32133/TCP
```

Getting my service, after its creation, I can see that I can reach port 9000 (in SDN), when connecting to port 32133 (outside SDN). You can "kubectl get nodes -o wide", to get a list of your nodes IP addresses, all of which would forward connections to your Pods

Comment: that requires an ingress controller though. Depending on OPs setup, they need a different solution. For example a service of type NodePort or LoadBalancer

Comment: OP specifically asks about ingresses though. Doesn't hint that it's not a suitable answer. Whereas NodePorts definitely isn't something I would recommend. Neither to new-comers, nor to my customers.

Comment: OP is asking if they *have* to use an ingress. The answer is actually no.

Comment: Feel free to post your own answer, explain us why NodePorts are more relevant than ingress. Here, or in general.

Comment: you are too caught up on NodePort. It is one of many ways. I just provided 2 examples next to using an ingress controller, with which you actaully have the same problem donw the line. How to you expose the ingress controller to the outside world? Do you use an ingress?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I choose the second solution with minio-nodeport, I get this minio-nodeport   NodePort    10.43.229.29   <none>        9000:32074/TCP   26s. How I can access my pod?